# Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

I'm trying to clone a repository on github, but keep getting this error.
The project in the Repo has firebase included in it, I don't know if this has any connection to the problem.

Please help me guys, I have tried all the solutions I have seen here on github, but none seems to work at all.

this is the error I get while trying to clone it:

```
Build file '/Users/mac/AndroidStudioProjects/UnterRideshare2/build.gradle.kts' line: 7

Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.3.15')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    MavenRepo
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:238)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$resolvePluginRequests$3(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:168)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:207)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:201)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolvePluginRequests(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:166)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:101)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.PluginRequestsHandler.handle(PluginRequestsHandler.kt:48)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.applyPluginsTo(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:195)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.applyPluginsTo(Interpreter.kt:398)
    at Program.execute(Unknown Source)
```

this is the content of my root gradle,

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath ("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")
    }
}

plugins {
    //trick: for the same plugin versions in all sub-modules
    id("com.google.gms.google-services").version("4.3.15").apply(false)
    id("com.android.application").version("7.4.0").apply(false)
    id("com.android.library").version("7.4.0").apply(false)
    kotlin("android").version("1.7.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.7.10").apply(false)
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin").version("2.0.1").apply(false)

}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -2):

1. Try using a VPN.
2. Invalidate cache and restart (VPN must be connected during restarting).
3. Check if the library version is compatible with your Gradle version.